# Assigning images to numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using random numbers, and the random number displays. But I want to do it so when a number appears an image shows instead of the number itself

E.g.

Number '5' gets picked.I want it so the number 5 gets replaced with a image of a number 5 which I make myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add "0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg" to your resources, and build the filename with `sprintf(buf, "%d.jpg",i)`

Comment: A more Objective C-way of doing this is `NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", i];`

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectedNumber = 5;

UIImage *numberImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", selectedNumber]];
```